# Can cookie be set on my own domain even the request is proxy from another server?

Tags: cookies, dns, reverse-proxy

So, here are the scenarios:

1) Normal situation

```
Request:
Client Browser ->(HTTP Request) -> MyServer.com 
Response:
MyServer.com -> (HTTP Response with Cookie on MyServer.com) -> clientBrowser
```

- Cookie is set in MyServer.com domain.

2) Proxy situation

```
Request:
Client Browser ->(HTTP Request) -> ProxyServer.com -> (Http Request) -> MyServer.com 
Response:
MyServer.com -> (HTTP Response with Cookie on MyServer.com) -> ProxyServer.com -> (Http Response with ???) -> clientBrowser
```

Questions are:

a) ProxyServer will see my cookie in the Http Response, right? (in the http response header).

b) Will ProxyServer.com be able to set the cookie (coming from Myserver.com ) in Myserver.com domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the domain of a cookie yourself while creating the cookie..

This is how it can be done in php

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

Google for other scripting languages..

Is this what you were looking for??

Comment: I don't think you can set cookie outside your domain. I have just tested it.  I'm just wondering if there is proxy in between (different domain), will it still stand true?

Comment: It should.. Shouldnt be a problem